# "if" and "until" give different results in bash scripting

Tags: bash, shell

Why is it that I get different results depending on if I have an `until` statement or an `if` statement?

```
# compare dates

a=12
b=8

if [ $a -le $b ]; then
    echo "it is not less than using if"
fi  

until [ $a -le $b ]
do
    echo "it is less than using until !?!?!?"
done
```

The `if` statement fails, but the `until` statement prints forever, even though they are the exact same condition.  Why?

Thank you.  This will really help my understanding.

Comment: `until condition` is equivalent to `while not condition`; i.e. `while condition == false`

Comment: Unitl loop executes while condition is false. http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_03.html

Comment: maybe start by getting familiar with conditionals and loop constructs, then it will become much clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> even though they are the exact same condition

This is incorrect. The `if` statement says "execute the following if the condition is *true*". The `until` statement says "execute the following if the condition is *false* (and keep executing it as long as the condition remains *false*)".

You may be thinking of the `while` statement. The `while` statement says "execute the following if the condition is *true* (and keep executing it as long as the condition remains *true*)".

Answer (score 0):

If is branch operator and until is a loop operator (that loops until the condition is met). In your case the condition is not met (12 is not less then or equal to 8) so it will loop indefinitely echoing inconsistent information with respect to the values of a and b.

Your if is wrong too because it would  echo "it is not less than using if" when a <= b and does nothing when it a > b.